# Finding the longest unique sequence of characters in a sequence of characters that do not fit in memory?

Tags: string, algorithm, sorting, memory, external

Say we have a large sequence of characters that is unable to fit in memory, and we want to find the longest span of characters such that none are repeated. How would you do this? I am familiar with concepts of external sorting, but do not see how we could apply similar techniques to a problem like this, since it seems processing a sequence of characters is entirely dependent on previous sequences.

Comment: Be more specific and provide examples of your dataset, the language you speak about and code or pseudocode examples of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Regardless of whether a sequence fits in memory or not the same algorithm that works on an in memory sequence, whether based on indexes or enumeration, can be adapted to work on data that does not fit in memory by implementing a seekable stream that provides the same interface as the in-memory algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start two pointers into the file at position 0, the front pointer and the back pointer.

Then advance the front pointer through the file, and as you do, advance the back pointer as necessary to ensure that the span between the back pointer and the front pointer contains no repeating characters.  This will be the longest span of unique characters that ends at the front pointer.

In order to do this, you just maintain a set containing all the characters between the back and front pointers.  If you want to advance the front pointer, and the character you pass is already in the set, then you must first advance the back pointer until the duplicate character is removed.

The longest span of characters you encounter in this way will be the longest span of unique characters in the file.

You can implement the two file pointers by opening the same file for reading twice.  Alternatively, you can open it just once and use a circular buffer to remember everything between the back and front.  There are only 256 (depending on your character type) unique characters so this buffer doesn't have to be too big.